# How to respawn automatically a process(wso2am)?

Tags: services, upstart, systemd, process, init.d

I have an upstart script as

```
   # Ubuntu upstart file at /etc/init/wso2am.conf
#!upstart
description "wso2am" 

pre-start script
    mkdir -p /var/log/wso2am/
end script

respawn
respawn limit 15 5

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]

script
    # Not sure why $HOME is needed, but we found that it is:
    export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_111"

    #exec /usr/local/bin/node $JAVA_HOME/node/notify.js 13002 >> /var/log/node.log 2>&1
end script
```

And my service file also created as

```
 # this is /usr/lib/systemd/system/wso2am.service
# (or /lib/systemd/system/wso2am.service dependent on 
#  your linux distribution flavor )
[Unit]
Description=wso2am server daemon
Documentation=https://docs.wso2.com/
After==network.target wso2am.service

[Service]
# see man systemd.service 
User=tel
Group=tel
TimeoutStartSec=0
Type=simple
KillMode=process
ExecStart= /bin/bash -lc '/home/tel/Documents/vz/wso2am-2.1.0/wso2am-2.1.0/bin/wso2server.sh --start'
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStop = /bin/bash -lc '/home/tel/Documents/vz/wso2am-2.1.0/wso2am-2.1.0/bin/wso2server.sh --stop'
StandardOutput=journal
Restart = always
RestartSec=2

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

I try to kill process (wso2am)

```
ps -ef | grep wso2am
Kill -9 process_id
```

[image: Process status]

But i can't able to find process automatically respawn/restart. How to check auto-respawn mechanism in ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue with help of Wso2 Team. Here, we have mention step for
system-D configuration issue.

System-D script for **wso2am.service** service file.

```
[Unit]
Description=wso2am server daemon
Documentation=https://docs.wso2.com/
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'XXX/Wso2serve start'
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c 'XXX/Wso2server.sh stop'
ExecRestart=/bin/sh -c 'XXX/Wso2server.sh restart'
PIDFile=/xxx/wso2carbon.pid
User=<Username>
Group=<groupname>
Type=forking
Restart=always
RestartSec=2
StartLimitInterval=60s
StartLimitBurst=3
StandardOutput=journal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now when you search for the wso2am process, use the below command.

```
ps -ef | grep java
```

Then pick the PID for the wso2am java process and kill it.

```
kill -9 <wso2_server_PID>
```

Immediately run

```
ps -ef | grep java
```

again and see that the process is not there now. Then within 2 seconds as we have specified **`RestartSec=2,`** you will see the wso2 server process is back up and running with a different PID

Thanks,
Vivek KT.