# Restart an app when it crashes

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, process

I state that I know practically nothing, I have found some solution that could do for my case but it is not quite how I would like it to be.
In practice I would like to create a script that when the start always remains active listening on a program, if the program closes by itself, it must reopen it.
I had found something like this:

```
 if ! pgrep -x "gedit" > /dev/null
 then
    echo "Stopped"
 fi
```

But first of all I would like you not to echo but to restart the app. 
And then I would like the scripr to always remain active. That is, I start it and until I stop it I do this thing.
Again, I am not an expert in these things and I am not studying this. I take care of everything else, so please ask for help because I need this.

EDIT:
Following the guides of Jos who replied to me I tried creating the file.service with:

```
 [Unit]
 Description=Sky linux restarting

 [Service]
 User=My pc name
 ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'sky'
 ExecStop=/bin/sh -c 'sky'
 ExecRestart=/bin/sh -c 'sky'
 Restart=always
 RestartSec=2

 [Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But when I run it with:
`sudo systemctl start your-service.service`
Does nothing

Comment: Why not try and fix the reason for these app crashes?

Comment: Because the app is not mine and I don't know about these things, I don't know in the least what it can be

Comment: What version Ubuntu? Edit your question and show me `ls -al /var/crash`. Also, in the service file, User= isn't your PC name, but your user ID, or root.

Comment: how do i write to you privately? we do first by continuing in a separate chat

Comment: We don't do private chat/email here. Sorry. Just add my info request as an edit to your question.

Comment: -rw-r-----  1 root     whoopsie 13435580 mar  7 15:53 _usr_lib_sky_sky.0.crash
-rw-r--r--  1 root     whoopsie        0 mar  7 15:53 _usr_lib_sky_sky.0.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie       37 mar  7 15:53 _usr_lib_sky_sky.0.uploaded
-rw-r-----  1 pingone     whoopsie 19374125 mar  7 09:22 _usr_lib_sky_sky.1000.crash
-rw-rw-r--  1 pingone     whoopsie        0 mar  7 09:22 _usr_lib_sky_sky.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie       37 mar  7 09:22 _usr_lib_sky_sky.1000.uploaded

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134622/discussion-between-luco-and-heynnema).

Comment: @heynnema If we knew or we were allowed to touch and fix the app that crashes, we wouldn't make or search such posts..

Answer (score 1):

Configure the script as a `systemd` service, then let `systemd` take care of starting, stopping and restarting the script.

If you google "Ubuntu create systemd service" you will find sites like https://www.shubhamdipt.com/blog/how-to-create-a-systemd-service-in-linux/ that tell you how to create a service. Basic steps are:

```
cd /etc/systemd/system
```

Create a file named `your-service.service` and include the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=<description about this service>

[Service]
User=<user e.g. root>
WorkingDirectory=<directory_of_script e.g. /root>
ExecStart=<script which needs to be executed>
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then reload the service daemon so your service is known to `systemd`:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

And start your service:

```
sudo systemctl start your-service.service
```

For a full example of a service that is restarted every time it crashes here: [How to respawn automatically a process(wso2am)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031868/how-to-respawn-automatically-a-processwso2am)

The main trick is to include these lines:

```
ExecRestart=/bin/sh -c 'name-of-script restart'
Restart=always
RestartSec=2
```

You can use the `restart` parameter to e.g. clean up or backup certain files before actually restarting, but you don't need to.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I added an edit to my question to answer you.

Comment: There is an error (a stray space) in your `ExecStart` command.

Comment: my typo in copying code, but in my file it is correct, now I have corrected here too

Comment: You shouldn't literally include the `'` quotes in your command, and include the whole pathname or include a correct working directory.

Comment: Are you referring to the directory of the program I want to restart?

Comment: Yes. In the `service` file that is the `WorkingDirectory` param. You need to give `systemd` a hint about where to find the script you want executed. If still nothing happens, look in `/var/log/syslog` where things go wrong or do `systemctl status your-service-name`.

Comment: ok gave me these logs:
`your-service.service: Failed to determine user credentials: No such process`
`your-service.service: Failed at step USER spawning / bin / sh: No such process`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134619/discussion-between-jos-and-luke).